# I want to stop the mousemove event when mouseup is fired.But it seems not working.How can i do that?

Tags: javascript, raphael

```
var paper = Raphael(10,10,700,500);
var backGround = paper.rect(10,10,600,400);
backGround.attr("fill", "#FFFFCC");

backGround.mousedown(function(){
    console.log("down");
    backGround.mousemove(function () {
       console.log("move");
    });
});

backGround.mouseup(function () {
    console.log("up");
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

after mouseup event is fired consolelog 'move' is still working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listeners are assigned once, and then always triggered. You may wanna set a flag:

```
 var down = false;
 backGround.mousedown(function(){
   console.log("down");
   down = true;
  });
  backGround.mouseup(function () {
    console.log("up");   
    down = false;
 });

 backGround.mousemove(function () {
   if(down){
     console.log("move");
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked.However why can't I use prevenrDefult() to bind events. ?

Comment: @nipun youre welcome ;), and yes shure you can. However its not related to the question....

Comment: I would be so grateful if you can give me an example using preventDefault(). to bind those events.

Comment: @nipun what? That doesnt make sense.